# C# and Base-to-Derived Class Casting

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I want to project info from a list of base-class instances into a list of derived-class instances, but I keep running into casting exceptions.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do... how do I make it work?

The following code is up at http://ideone.com/CaXQS , if that helps... thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AddingReversedNumbers
{
        public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass, IMyInterface
        {
                public int InterfaceProperty { get; set; }
                public int DerivedClassProperty { get; set; }
                public List<int> DerivedClassList { get; set; }
        }

        public class MyBaseClass
        {
                public int BaseClassProperty { get; set; }
        }

        public interface IMyInterface
        {
                int InterfaceProperty { get; set; }
        }

        class Program
        {
                static void Main()
                {
                        //// This code works just fine.
                        //var derivedList = new List<MyDerivedClass>();
                        //derivedList.Add(new MyDerivedClass { BaseClassProperty = 10, DerivedClassProperty = 20, InterfaceProperty = 30 });
                        //derivedList.Add(new MyDerivedClass { BaseClassProperty = 20, DerivedClassProperty = 40, InterfaceProperty = 60 });
                        //var baseList = derivedList.ConvertAll(x => (MyBaseClass)x);

                        // This code breaks when ConvertAll() is called.
                        var baseList = new List<MyBaseClass>();
                        baseList.Add(new MyBaseClass{ BaseClassProperty = 10 });
                        baseList.Add(new MyBaseClass{ BaseClassProperty = 20 });
                        var derivedList = baseList.ConvertAll(x => (MyDerivedClass)x);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: The items inside of `baseList` are not of type `MyDerivedClass`, so the cast will always fail... What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think this is better described as 'Upcasting'.  Is there a reason that you are not just adding instances of DerivedClass to your List<MyBaseClass> directly?

Comment: For each item in the list, I want to populate a new of instance of MyDerivedClass with all of the info that's in MyBaseClass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `ConvertAll` code you're *just* casting. You can't cast a base class instance to a derived class instance. For example, what would you expect casting `object` to `FileStream` to do? Which file would it refer to?

If you want to create a *new* object in the `ConvertAll` projection, just do that:

```
var derivedList = baseList.ConvertAll
      (x => new MyDerivedClass { BaseClassProperty = x.BaseClassProperty });
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing, but I was hoping to avoid explicitly coding the redundant mapping.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the mapping, but if it makes sense you could always add a constructor on MyDerivedClass that takes in a MyBaseClass to encapsulate the mapping between the two in one place.

Comment: It's not the answer I was hoping for, but it's the answer nonetheless.  Thank you!